# turn mysql select to delete statement - How do I?

Tags: mysql

I only want to delete from one table, but I have to select based on criteria from a related table. The example I found on here earlier talks about deleting from one table.

How do I turn the following select into a delete statement?

```
select r.id, r.reminder_date, c.full_name, c.company
from reminders r
left join clients c
on r.client_id = c.id
where (c.full_name is null
or c.full_name = "")
AND (c.company is  null
or c.company = "");
```

Thank you

Comment: You want to delete from reminders or from clients or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

```
delete reminders
from reminders r
left join clients c
on r.client_id = c.id
where (c.full_name is null
or c.full_name = "")
AND (c.company is  null
or c.company = "");
```

Comment: Isn't a left join dangerous in this case?

Comment: Seems like he wants to delete from reminders where there isn't an associated client... so it makes sense in this case.

Comment: I think that's what he wants actually. He's searching for reminders for clients without a name. He will now delete reminders for clients without a name, as well as reminders for clients that don't exist.

Comment: Elijakim, that's it. I'm trying to delete reminders where a client doesn't have a name. Thanks everyone!